# Testing a Defiant timer

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm not sure if I can do this but I'm trying a simple test on my Defiant timer. I have a two wire extension going to the Defiant into the appropriate line (hot) and load terminals. My problem is what to do with the lamp holder and its two wires. How would they interface with the Defiant? I tried one configuration and tripped the breaker (oops!). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

[image]
Defiant timer and a simple light holder

Comment: Specific model? Have you looked at it's installation instructions? Guessing is not a good option.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The model is #32648. I've already successfully wired one of these controlling our patio lights. It stopped working after a week or so. I had it wired correctly with the neutral wiring that I don't have with this simple setup leaving me wondering if this is an exercise in futility. The timer I'm using I had as a spare and I'm wanting to simply see if it works using just a 60 watt bulb without having to pull the wiring apart that currently just has a simple rocker on/off switch I put in to replace the timer that stopped working. Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Wiring diagram from the manual (swiped from Home Depot's website):
[image]

So if you're wiring this up on a test bench:[image]

The Hot side of your power source goes to the timer's Line terminal.

The timer's Load terminal should be connected to the Hot terminal or wire of the thing you want to control (in your example, the light).

The Neutral from your power source goes *both* to the light's Neutral terminal/wire (completing the circuit to power the the light) and to the timer's Neutral terminal (completing the circuit to power the timer).

Ideally, Ground from your power source goes *both* to the timer's Ground terminal and to the light's Ground terminal/wire.

WARNING: DO NOT APPLY POWER UNTIL AFTER EVERYTHING IS WIRED AND INSULATED. DO NOT TOUCH ANY TERMINALS WHILE CIRCUIT IS POWERED. DO NOT PULL ON WIRES. DAMAGE, INJURY OR DEATH *IS* POSSIBLE. In fact, I would strongly suggest that you make the connections inside an electrical box and mount the timer to the face of that; one-space "old work" plastic boxes are cheap and will help keep your fingers away from the terminals while you are operating the timer's controls.

(If you're asking this question, you do need that warning.)

Comment: Thanks Ed, got the photo of a safer test setup.

Comment: And guess what? The second night it stopped working. No more Defiant Timers in this household! The comment in this thread about my cooking this device may be correct!

Comment: Assuming you mean the display went blank and it isn't responding to the buttons: You may want to recheck the connections before assuming the problem is the timer itself. And of course make sure there's no other switch that could have turned it off, and that the breaker didn't blow (which could also be a connection coming loose). If the display is working, check the wiring on that side, and of course check the bulb
.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It's baffling that the first night it clicked on at 4pm and off at 9. The second night, 4pm came and went without powering on the bulb and the timer screen was blank. The breaker was fine as we would not have been able to power on other lamps in the house. I should Google to see if others have had similar issues or maybe there's some fine print in the instructions that I failed to see! Again, thanks for talking the time to entertain my frustrations with this thing!

Comment: Was the clock in the switch still running and correct and set to the right half of the day? If clock thought it was 4AM and timer was set for 4 PM or vice versa... There may also be day-of-week settings; check the manual.

Comment: The time's correct [8:02pm (Tucson, AZ.), and date - 12/26, Mon]. The ON/OFF times are also correct: 4pm/9pm. Mystery. I wonder if the timer's display is supposed to remain visible however dim.

Comment: I found a timer by Honeywell that may prove to be more reliable.

Answer (score 14):

STOP! You are on the verge of tripping your breaker or starting a fire!

You wrote that you wired a power cord to line and load. This is just wrong! You connect the cord to line and **neutral**. Then you connect the lamp to load and neutral. Thus, you will have two wires connected to the neutral terminal. You may need to use a short piece of wire as a pigtail and connect the three wires with a wirenut.

Comment: I already tripped the breaker! Thanks so much for your intervention and saving me from my ignorance (stupidity?!). It's been frustrating having wired the first timer and seeing it work for a week and then having it just stop working. Of course, I followed the instructions in wiring our patio lights and decided to wing it with this little experiment. As has been shared, not a good idea, especially when it comes to electricity! Again, many thanks!

Comment: To the OP: your earlier experiment may have cooked the timer, so it may not work at all now.

Comment: Thanks. The price I'll have to pay for trying to cut corners. We'll see.

Comment: Just a quick note: as with smart switches, this will require that both hot and neutral be available where you want to put it. That's easy when plugging in n or when power goes to the switch before the light, but may be a serious challenge it it's replacing a switch installed as a switch loop.